# React js - Use only one state instead of multiple state to handle "event.target.value"

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React js. I created an app that have input fields and when you click the submit button the value of the input fields will display in console.log depends on the value entered in input fields. The question is can i use only one state to display the following that I entered in the input fields?

this is my code:

```
constructor () {
  super ();
  this.state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    place: '',
    birthPlace: '',
  }
}

username = () => {
  this.setState({ username: event.target.value })
}

password = () => {
  this.setState({ password: event.target.value })
}

place = () => {
  this.setState({ place: event.target.value })
}

birthPlace = () => {
  this.setState({ birthPlace: event.target.value })
}
```

What I want to happen is use only one state for username, password, place, birthPlace (if possible) and what I want to happen is when I click the submit button, the value of which I've type in the Input fields should display in console.log

Just for optimization purposes. Thanks for the help

Comment: There are multiple ways to have this solution, controlled component, and uncontrolled component. In the case of the Controlled component, each input field can be associated with its own state. In uncontrolled component, you can have only one state object and mofify it when you click submit

Answer (score 0):

Its probably better to use hooks for this, something like the code below would do it

```
    import React , {useState} from 'react'

    const myComp = () =>{

    const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({})


    handleOnChange({target:{value, id}}) =>{
    let newState = Object.assign({}, userDetails, {[id]: value})
     setUserDetails(newState)
    }

 return (
<form>   
    <input type='text'  id='name' value={userDetails['name']} onChange={handleOnChange} />
    <input type='password'  id='password' value={userDetails['password']} onChange={handleOnChange} />
    <input type='email'  id='email' value={userDetails['email']} onChange={handleOnChange} />
</form>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the dictionary objects.
Define your state like this

    constructor () {
        super ();
        this.state = {
            formvalues:{}
        }
    }

and you can update your values by defining any key you want.

   this.setState(prevState => ({
       formvalues: {
           ...prevState.formvalues,
            [username]: value
        }
    }))

and you can access any input field based on the key you defines.

`console.log(this.state.formvalues.username)`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor () {
  super ();
  this.state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    place: '',
    birthPlace: '',
  }
}
```

You can use one method for all values like while using the same state:

```
handleChange = event => {
    const { value, name } = event.target;

    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example that uses [React hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html):

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    username: '',
    password: '',
    place: '',
    birthPlace: '',
  });
  
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(value);
    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value
    }));  
  }
  
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log(state);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>UserName</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" value={state.username} onChange={handleChange} /><br />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" value={state.password} onChange={handleChange} /><br />
      <label>Place</label>
      <input type="text" name="place" value={state.place} onChange={handleChange} /><br />
      <label>BirthPlace</label>
      <input type="text" name="birthPlace" value={state.birthPlace} onChange={handleChange} /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 80px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that setting the state directly with the `event.target.value` will not always produce the expecting result.

React uses the [Synthetic event wrapper](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) and to be able to update the state directly with the `event.target.value` it uses `persist()` to make the event persist long enough to be used in the `setState()` method.

What I suggest doing to use `event.target.value` in class components is to store the value and then update the state.

So instead of doing this:

```
username = (event) => {
  this.setState({ username: event.target.value })
}
```

You do this:

```
username = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ username: value })
}
```

This way the value is preserved long after the event has been fired.

You will notice that I added the `event` as parameter in the above example. This is to answer your second part of the question regarding on how to update the state. You need to constantly call the username method each time the typed username is changed. You can do this by calling it via the `onChange` listener:

```
<input name='username' onChange = {(event) => this.username(event)} />
```